# page of FLASK app is not changing after uploading a file, progress bar works fine

Tags: python, flask, redirect, file-upload

I want to perform some analysis on a text file. Once file is uploaded in the webpage, I am trying to redirect the route, But that isn't working. Surprisingly, print statement is running in the console of the redirected route, but the template isn't rendering.

Debug mode is true, I have multiple times ran this command set FLASK_DEBUG=1. I desperately need help :( Any help will be really appreciated.

imo there is some issue in javascript, which is not letting python change url.

My front end page is

```
<body>
    <div class="split left" >
        
        <img src="/static/acgt.png" class="logo"/>
        
        <h2><u>Description<br/><br/></u></h2>
        
        <p>There are some text in here</p>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        
        <div class="file-upload">
            <input class="file-upload__input" type="file" name="myFile" id="myFile" oninput="upload('{{ request.url }}');">
            <button class="file-upload__button" type="button" >Upload FASTA file from your device</button>
            <span class="file-upload__label"></span>
            
        </div>
        
        <div id="progress_wrapper" class="d-none">
            <label id="progress_status" style="color: white;">50% uploaded</label>
            <div class="progress mb-3">
                <div id="progress" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
            </div>
        </div> 

        <div >
            <p class = "errorMsg" style="margin-top: 20px; color:#FF6347 ; font-size:1.3em;">{{errorMessage}}</p>
        </div>
        
    </div>
    
    <div class="split right">
        
    </div>
    
    <script>
        
        const btn = document.querySelector('.file-upload__button')
        const hiddenInput = btn.parentElement.querySelector('.file-upload__input');
        const label = btn.parentElement.querySelector('.file-upload__label');
        const defaultLabelText = '';
        
        label.textContent = defaultLabelText;
        label.title = defaultLabelText;
        
        
        btn.addEventListener('click', function ( ) {
            hiddenInput.click();
        });
        
        hiddenInput.addEventListener('change',function() {
            const filename = Array.prototype.map.call(hiddenInput.files, function (file) {
                return file.name;
            });
            label.textContent = filename || defaultLabelText;  
        });  
        
        
        function upload(url) {
            
            var progress_wrapper = document.getElementById("progress_wrapper");
            
            progress_wrapper.classList.remove("d-none");
            
            var progress = document.getElementById("progress");
            
            var progress_status = document.getElementById("progress_status");
            
            var data = new FormData();
            
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            
            request.responseType = "json";
            
            var file = hiddenInput.files[0];
            console.log(typeof(file));
            
            var filename = file.name;
            console.log(filename)
            var filesize = file.size;
            document.cookie = `filesize=${filesize}`;
            
            data.append("file", file);
            
            request.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (e) {
                
                // Get the loaded amount and total filesize (bytes)
                var loaded = e.loaded;
                var total = e.total
                
                // Calculate percent uploaded
                var percent_complete = (loaded / total) * 100;
                
                // Update the progress text and progress bar
                progress.setAttribute("style", `width: ${Math.floor(percent_complete)}%`);
                progress_status.innerText = `${Math.floor(percent_complete)}% uploaded`;
                
            });

            request.addEventListener("loadend",function(e){
                if(request.status == 200) {
                    console.log("Success should be shown using alert")
                    
                }else{
                    console.log("Failed to upload the file, Sad life :(")
                }
            });

            request.open("post", url);
            request.send(data);
        }
        
    </script>
    
</body>
```

and python page is

```
@app.route('/home', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def hello_world():
    if request.method == "POST":

        filesize = request.cookies.get("filesize")
        file = request.files["file"]
        res = make_response(jsonify({"message" : f"{file.filename} uploaded"}), 200)
        return redirect(url_for('dummyroute'))

    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/dummyroute')
def dummyroute():
    print("This is getting printed in console")
    return '<h1>I am getting mad<h1>'
```

Comment: did you restarted `Flask`?

Comment: maybe first you should debug code. In python you can use `print()` to see what you have in variable and which part of code is executed. And in JavaScript you can also use `console.log()` to display values in javascript console in DevTools in Chrome/Firefox.

Comment: if you use `JavaScript`/`AJAX` to execute `hello_world()` then redirection is send to this JavaScript code and browser will not use it. You have to get this information in JavaScript and use JavaScript to redirect browser - `document.url = '/dummyroute'`. AJAX was invented to NOT reload page.

Comment: using `redirect` and `make_response` at the same time is useless - server may send only one response - `redirect` or response with your JSON data. It can't send two responses. You should rather use `return res` to send JSON data to JavaScript and it should redirect browser.

Comment: @furas ,I have restarted flask multiple times. I have used print statements in python. Thet are printing all the prints in dummyroute, but the html of dummyroute was not being displayed in web. But thanks to the answer below, I can change the flask route independently using ajax(javascript)

Comment: @furas , Thank you veery much for you help, I really appreciate your :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use JavaScript/AJAX to send `request` then `response` is send to this JavaScript code - and JavaScript's request is redirected to `/dummyroute` and JavaScript gets response from `/dummyroute` but browser will not try to use this `response` to `redirect` full page.

AJAX was invented to NOT reload full page and browser doesn't reload/redirect page when you use AJAX.

You will have do redirect full page directly in JavaScript - `document.location = '/dummyroute'`

Comment: Thank you very much, "document.location = '/dummyroute' " is working.